# how to extract unique values from pandas data frame on a weekly basis

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a pandas dataframe which looks like this below from which I need to extract all the unique user ids on a weekly basis:-

```
    sender_user_id    created
0   2                 2016-12-19 03:34:30.013923
1   3                 2016-12-20 03:34:30.013923 
2   6                 2016-12-21 03:34:30.013923 
3   22                2016-12-22 03:34:30.013923
3   6                 2016-12-22 06:34:30.013923
```

I need an output dictionary or dataframe which aggregates all the unique user_ids on a weekly basis which looks something like this

```
    created                         user_ids
0   2016-12-19 03:34:30.013923      2,5,24,15,6
1   2016-12-25 03:34:30.013923      8,9,14,21,5
```

I have an idea that we could split the dataframes on a weekly basis and use the
numpy.unique() function but is there a good and optimised way to do this?

Comment: where did `2016-12-25 03:34:30.013923` come from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

consider this randomly generated `df`

```
rng = np.arange(100)
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['sender_user_id', 'created'])
for t in pd.date_range('2016-03-31', periods=10, freq='3B'):
    for i in np.random.permutation(rng)[:5]:
        df = df.append(dict(sender_user_id=i, created=t), ignore_index=True)

df.sender_user_id = df.sender_user_id.astype(int)
```

***`resample` with `on`***

```
df.resample('W', on='created').sender_user_id.unique().reset_index(name='user_ids')
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> try this:

```
def aggregate_function (df, col_1, col_2):

    new_df = pd.DataFrame([], columns=[col_1, col_2])
    new_df[col_1] = sorted (set (df[col_1]))

    new_df[col_2] = new_df[col_1].map(lambda x: sorted (set (df.loc[df[col_1]==x, col_2])))

    return (new_df)

>>> aggregate_function (df, 'created', 'user_ids')
>>>     created                         user_ids
             0   2016-12-19 03:34:30.013923      2,5,24,15,6
             1   2016-12-25 03:34:30.013923      8,9,14,21,5
```